# Error with print: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have code for concatenation of two string but it is showing me an error.

Here is the code :

```
Name = "Praveen kumar"
print (Name)+"Good boy"
```

Error message : `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: `print('{} Good boy'.format(Name))`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid can u plzz explain this??

Comment: Have a look at [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is a function, returning None.

So when you write

```
print(Name) + "Good boy"
```

You are actually adding the return value of the function call (i.e. None) to the string.

What you wanted instead was probably:

```
print(Name, "Good boy")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing `Name` and then adding the string `Good boy` to it, you need to enclose your addition within the function call.

`print(Name)` will return `None` (it is a function which defines no return value) which is why you're getting the `unsupported operand...` error.

The code below will achieve what you want.

```
Name = "Praveen kumar"
print(Name + "Good boy")
```

However note that there will be no space between `Name` and `'Good boy'`. If you want a space then you can use `print(Name, "Good boy")` as the default separator is `sep = ' '`, meaning that a space will be added between your arguments.

Comment: probably they want whitespace though

Comment: @wim (Name, "Good boy") is giving me result with space of one definite length. what shall I do If i want to provide some extra space in between this two..???

Comment: @PraveenKumar in that case you can pass the keyword argument `print(Name, "Good boy", sep='   ')`. In that case I've manually typed 3 spaces but you could also do `sep = ' '*3`