# Want to add the text kg’s after accepting weight input

Tags: python

I’m new to Python and programming altogether. As I’m going through my first few online lessons, I’m trying to add text to the users weight i.e. 70kg’s

My code that works is as follows:

weight_lbs = input(“Please enter your weight in pounds? “)

weight_kg = int(weight_lbs) * 0.45

print(weight_kg)

Nb: the above code works but does not display the text “kg’s” after the number.

I’ve tried:
print(weight_kg) + “kg’s”
or
print(weight_kg + “kg’s”)
or
print(weight_kg), “kg’s”

Unfortunately I keep getting error, unsupported operand type(s) for +: ‘NoneType’ and ‘Str’

Thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is the preferred way to concatenate a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error with print: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422819/error-with-print-unsupported-operand-types-for-nonetype-and-str)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25675943/2745495)

Comment: @wwii no, that's definitely the wrong one here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
print(f"{weight_kg}kg's")
```

or simply

```
print(str(weight_kg)+"kg's")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The second one definitely did the trick. Did not quite understand the syntax in the first one though but that’s okay..I’ll remember the second solution going forward 